# Deleting multiple cells at the same time shows runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel

Deleting by selecting single cell works without any issue. But selecting multiple cells and then trying to delete gives

> runtime error 13

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const sRng As String = "A5:AQ155" ' change as required
Dim sOld As String
Dim sNew As String
Dim sCmt As String
Dim iLen As Long


If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then


    With Target
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        sNew = .Value2
        Application.Undo
        sOld = .Value2
        .Value2 = sNew

        Application.EnableEvents = True

        sCmt = "Edit: " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " by " & Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Previous Text :- " & sOld
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then
            .AddComment
        Else
            iLen = Len(.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text)
        End If

        With .Comment.Shape.TextFrame
            .AutoSize = True
            .Characters(Start:=iLen + 1).Insert IIf(iLen, vbLf, "") & sCmt
        End With

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime error 13 is a *type mismatch*. The error is being thrown from the following line (and possibly others too):

```
sOld = .Value2
```

---

You're getting an error because `sOld` is a `String` which accepts a single value and `.Value2` is trying to return a multi-value variant array. The two aren't compatible. `Target` is a range which represents the cells you've deleted. This could be one cell, or it could be many.

---

To fix this you need to loop through each cell in `Target`. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'declarations
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(sRng)) Is Nothing Then
        For Each r In Target
            With r
                'rest of code
            End With
        Next r
    End If
End Sub
```